# Linux Server RMI with Windows Client Connection refused

Tags: java, linux, rmi

I've tried all I've read about this problem and I don't get it fixed. Because of that i will give it a chance that anyone else got the same error and nothing could fix it. A friend of me have a root Server where other Java Application over Network runs. I've opened the Port in the IPTables (1099 Registry). I start the Registry in the Server Code. I setup the System.property hostname Address of the Server to an address like 91.54.2.10 and in the other ipaddress fields. On localhost everything is fine, but not in the linux world.
I've pinged the Server : OK, I've netstatted with netstat -napt | grep 1099 and the Port ist Listening my Server comes up with [Server] Listening on Port 1099 and the Client tries to connect. After a few seconds the Server pushes an Exception with Connection time out.
Ive set up the /etc/hosts 
127.0.1.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
PublicADRESS localhost

I dont know whats the matter?! Ive tryed everything could anyone understand why this wont work?

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/runningserveriqa4wy61x0.png

Client

```
public void generateConnection() {
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "client.java.policy");
if (System.getSecurityManager()==null) {
    System.setSecurityManager( new RMISecurityManager() );
} else {
}
try {
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(xx.xx.xx.xx, Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
    chatserver = (CServer) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+xx.xx.xx.xx+"/server");
    CClientImpl client = new CClientImpl();
    client.setUsername(username);
    chatserver.login(client);
} catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server is not online!");
    connectbutton.setEnabled(true);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}



public class ChatServer {

public static ChatServer instance;

public static ChatServer getInstance() {
    if(instance==null) {
        instance = new ChatServer();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void generateNetwork() {
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "server.policy");
    if (System.getSecurityManager()==null) {
        System.setSecurityManager( new RMISecurityManager() );
    } 
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "xx.xx.xx.xx");
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        CServerImpl chatserver = CServerImpl.getInstance();
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/server", chatserver);
        System.out.println("[Server] Listening on Port "+Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChatServer.getInstance().generateNetwork();
}

}
```

Comment: Connection timeout or connection refused. Which is it?

Comment: As in the picture it is Connection refused Exception and in the next line: Connection timed out